# "java.lang.NullPointerException" exception in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

This android activity is not running. Could anyone help me.It shows following error.
When i click this to start another activity, it does not run.

I am not able to find this error.

Anybody could fix it?

Errors:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingandroid/com.example.testingandroid.SumsMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 12:57:22.958: E/AndroidRuntime(791):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
```

Code

```
package com.example.testingandroid;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

public class SelectTitle extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
public int entryNo;
RadioButton r1;RadioButton r2;RadioButton r3;RadioButton r4;
RadioButton r5;RadioButton r6;RadioButton r7;RadioButton r8;
RadioButton r9;RadioButton r10;RadioButton r11;RadioButton r12;
RadioButton r13;
int determiner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_title);
        r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.MasteryPack);
        r2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Simplification); 
        r3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.FractionsandRatios);
        r4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Number);
        r5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Average);
        r6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.TimeandWork);
        r7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.TimeandDistance);
        r8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Interest);
        r9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Measurement);
        r10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Percentage);
        r11 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.BoatandTrain);
        r12 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Practice);

        r1.setOnClickListener(this);
        r2.setOnClickListener(this);
        r3.setOnClickListener(this);
        r4.setOnClickListener(this);
        r5.setOnClickListener(this);
        r6.setOnClickListener(this);
        r7.setOnClickListener(this);
        r8.setOnClickListener(this);
        r9.setOnClickListener(this);
        r10.setOnClickListener(this);
        r11.setOnClickListener(this);
        r12.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_title, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.MasteryPack:
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);

            nextScreen.putExtra("determiner", 1);
            startActivity(nextScreen);
            break;

        case R.id.Simplification:
            Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            //String "determiner" = null;
            nextScreen1.putExtra("determiner", 2);
            startActivity(nextScreen1);
            break;

        case R.id.FractionsandRatios:
            Intent nextScreen2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen2.putExtra("determiner", 3);
            startActivity(nextScreen2);
            break;

        case R.id.Number:
            Intent nextScreen3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen3.putExtra("determiner", 4);
            startActivity(nextScreen3);
            break;

        case R.id.Average:
            Intent nextScreen4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen4.putExtra("determiner", 5);
            startActivity(nextScreen4);
            break;

        case R.id.TimeandWork:
            Intent nextScreen5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen5.putExtra("determiner", 6);
            startActivity(nextScreen5);
            break;

        case R.id.TimeandDistance:
            Intent nextScreen6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen6.putExtra("determiner", 7);
            startActivity(nextScreen6);
            break;

        case R.id.Interest:
            Intent nextScreen7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen7.putExtra("determiner", 8);
            startActivity(nextScreen7);
            break;

        case R.id.Measurement:
            Intent nextScreen8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen8.putExtra("determiner", 9);
            startActivity(nextScreen8);
            break;

        case R.id.Percentage:
            Intent nextScreen9 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen9.putExtra("determiner", 10);
            startActivity(nextScreen9);
            break;

        case R.id.BoatandTrain:
            Intent nextScreen10 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen10.putExtra("determiner", 11);
            startActivity(nextScreen10);
            break;

        case R.id.Practice:
            Intent nextScreen11 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SumsMain.class);
            nextScreen11.putExtra("determiner", 12);
            startActivity(nextScreen11);
            break;



        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: post the full stack trace.

Comment: Also, post the `onCreate()` of `SumsMain`. The error is most likely in that class.

Comment: Can you post the content of `R.layout.activity_select_title`?

Comment: I think there should be problem when you are retrieving the value from getIntent () so please post the code of SumsMain class onCreate() Method.

Answer (score 0):

To move  from one activity to another we generally use Intents in which we have to write the name of the class Activity in which we want to move.

In your code you must create a SumMain class before running your code.

There is no need of declaring   putExtra key you can use it directly as you  declared it 
int  determiner

Comment: If this were the case the exception would be `NoClassDefFound` not `NPE`. And from the code we see, the `putExtra()` is not causing the `NPE`

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that you are using any object which not created yet. Check it...